# 2 matchcollections to 1 list

Tags: c#, regex

Hi guys I have 2 MatchCollection:

```
MatchCollection users_ids = Regex.Matches(result, @"url"":""(.*?)""");
MatchCollection users_names = Regex.Matches(result, @"fullname"":""(.*?)""");
```

The number of mathces of 2 collections is equаl

I need to join all Matches to 1 List. Smth like this:

```
                foreach (Match match in users_ids)
                {
                   string id = match.Groups[1].Value.ToString();
                  // string name = users_names(every match) .Groups[1].Value.ToString();
                   online_list.Add(id + "|" + name);
                }
```

Any solutions?=\

Comment: Is that not working? What is the question?

Comment: Can you give some sample input? What does `result` contain?

Comment: How to add to foreach loop the elements of second collection? Smtth like **foreach (Match match in users_ids && Match match2 in users_names)**

Comment: @Analcrab And the answer is [Zip](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14447738/1159478).  (Or a `for` loop, but that's much less fun.)

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the perfect application of `Zip`, which goes through two enumerations, taking the item at the current index of each and mapping them into a result using the given function:

```
var matches = users_ids.Cast<Match>()
    .Zip(users_names.Cast<Match>(),
    (id, name) => id.Groups[1].Value + "|" + name.Groups[1].Value);
```